# R - Programming: How to loop through a list of dataframes and manipulate specific columns within each?

Tags: r, list, lapply

So I have three data frames, each with 14 columns.

```
iowa <- data.frame() #Has 14 columns; let's say 600 records
maine <- data.frame() #Has same 14 columns; let's say 700 records
texas <- data.frame() #Has same 14 columns; let's say 900 records
```

I place those data frames within a list,

```
state_List <- list(iowa, maine, texas)
```

I then want to change two columns (called "State_Date" and "US_Date") within each data frame within the state_List to date formats, and I would like to change all columns except to one as factors.  I have written the following:

```
state_List <- lapply(state_List,
                     function(x){
                                 x$State_Date <- as.Date(x$State_Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
                                 x$US_Date <- as.Date(x$US_Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
                                 x[, c(1:7, 9:14)] <- as.factor(x[, c(1:7, 9:14)]
                                 }
                     )
```

The error I receive is

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

This error is due to the as.factor part.

However, if I get rid of the last evaluation of the function called in lapply, and just keep the two that change the class of the date fields, what I get is:

1. A list where the 3 names of the data frames it contained are lost
2. Each data frame in the list, or should I say each slot for a data frame in the list is now filled with the US_Date column for that state.

What I'd like is:

1. A list with 3 data frames (that retains the name of the data frames)
2. Within each data frame, the two fields, State_Date and US_Date have dates that have been formatted as such
3. All columns except for column 8 to be formatted as factors

Thank you for your help!

**** CORRECT CODE BELOW SHOWS WHAT I SHOULD HAVE DONE BASED ON THE RESPONSE:

```
state_List <- list(iowa = iowa, maine = maine, texas = texas)
state_List <- lapply(state_List,
                     function(X){
                                 x$State_Date <- as.Date(x$State_Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
                                 x$US_Date <- as.Date(x$US_Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
                                 x[, c(1:7, 9:14)] <- lapply( x[, c(1:7, 9:14)] , factor)
                                 return(x)
                                 }
                    )
```

Comment: This question is very well written and shows what you've tried. Thanks for that. Rather than posting your final solution in your question (because that can be confusing to readers), it is better to post as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third line inside that functions should be:

```
x[, c(1:7, 9:14)] <- lapply( x[, c(1:7, 9:14)] , factor)
```

And you should `return(x)` at the end.

Comment: First, that is an outstanding answer.  Works nicely.  Now, were I to want to retain the names of the data frames within the list, would I simply need to have a vector holding them with which I could assign them after the global lapply function?

That is, must I save the names of the data frames within the list, to reassign them after the lapply function, or is there a way to retain the names of x?  Must I type    names(x) <- names(x)

Comment: I would have expected the names of stateList to be the same after the `<-lapply()`. Are you telling me that the names were lost? (And do not bother trying to discover what the names were from within the function. That is a hopeless task.)

Comment: They were.  Here is what is returned:

    >names(state_List)

    >NULL


can't figure out how to type code in the comments

Comment: Well ... they never did have names in the first place did they?

Comment: Absolutely Correct!  I should have written list(iowa = iowa, etc...).  Thank you!  I appreciate your patience with that one.  It's pretty amazing how quickly you spotted that.  I'd have probably spent an hour, overlooking an assumption).  Thank you.